# Validating Asp.net Dropdownlist with bootstrap validator ,the validator has not trigger

Tags: asp.net, twitter-bootstrap, validation

Dropdownlist using Bootstrap in asp.net

Files include:

- bootstrap.select.css
- bootsrap.select.js
- bootstrapValidator.css

HTML:

```
<div class="col-md-6 form-horizontal" id="SelectForm">
  <div class="form-group">
    <div class="input-group">
      <asp:DropDownList ID="ddlBrand"  runat="server" CssClass="selectpicker" ValidationGroup="quote">
        <asp:ListItem>Select</asp:ListItem>
        <asp:ListItem>Kanpur</asp:ListItem>
        <asp:ListItem>Kanpur</asp:ListItem>
        <asp:ListItem>Rewa</asp:ListItem>
        <asp:ListItem>Bhopal</asp:ListItem>
        <asp:ListItem>Indore</asp:ListItem>
        <asp:ListItem>Jabalpur</asp:ListItem>
      </asp:DropDownList>
    </div>
  </div>
<asp:Button ID="btnQuote" runat="server" Text="Calculate Premium" CssClass="btn btn-block org3"/>
</div>
```

jQuery validation using validate.js

This is the javascript used for validation of dropdownlist.

```
$(document).ready(function () {
  $('#SelectForm').find('[name="ddlBrand"]').selectpicker()
    .change(function (e) {
      $('#SelectForm').bootstrapValidator('revalidateField', 'ddlBrand');
    }).end()
      .bootstrapValidator({
        framework: 'bootstrap',
        excluded: ':disabled',
        icon: {
          valid: 'glyphicon glyphicon-ok',
          invalid: 'glyphicon glyphicon-remove',
          validating: 'glyphicon glyphicon-refresh'
        },
        fields: {
          ddlBrand: {
            validators: {
              notEmpty: {
                message: 'Please choose '
              }
            }
          }
        }
     });
});
```

Bootstrap validator is not working properly .

Comment: you are going to want to rephrase your question. What about the bootstrap validator is not working. Are you receiving any javascript errors? etc...

Comment: I'm validating dropdownlist with bootstrap validator , but the validator has not trigger.

Answer (score 0):

Okay, try this. I had somewhere the same issue. 
Open your page and right click on the dropdownlist, 
after right clicking go to inspect element, 
In inspect element you'll see your name would be twisted to something infamous and random text with the actual name appended at the end, copy that name and replace it with your existing validator name.
I hope this helps. 
Also do the same for ids in your form.